# jsoup: selecting table without specific ID that contains certain text string (select two conditions)

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to extract the quotes from the following forum:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1772338

All worked with:

```
Elements postquote = doc.select("table[cellpadding=6][cellspacing=0]");
```

BUT: The problem in this particular thread is, that the editor used the quoting-format to format his text and not to quote another user.

My approach was to search aditionally for "Originally Posted by"

```
Elements postquote = doc.select("table[cellpadding=6][cellspacing=0], table:contains(Originally Posted by)");
```

- How can I combine two ore more select conditions? (Jsoup syntax states "," but that does not work)
- What's wrong? How could I extract the REAL Posts more easy?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do. Id you want to find `table[cellpadding=6][cellspacing=0]` that also contains `Originally Posted by` then just use `doc.select("table[cellpadding=6][cellspacing=0]:contains(Originally Posted by)")`. Also `,` represents `OR` so it will try to find `somethingLikeThis OR somethingLikeThat`.

Comment: OK!! Great!! that solved my question. I was not aware that nothing ` ` means `AND` and `,` means `OR`

Comment: one more thing:
on this syntax page: http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html
They state in the section combinators the following:
 `E, F, G` all matching elements E, F, or G  `a[href], div, h3`
That made me using the `,`as `AND`
What do I misunderstand there?

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are trying to solve with `a[href], div, h3`. This selector will select all anchors `a[href]`, all `div`s, all `h3` headings. It is the same as [union of all sets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) which in [logic is represented as OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction).

Comment: Ok thanks, that made it very clear! TOP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find `table[cellpadding=6][cellspacing=0]` that also contains `Originally Posted by` then just use

```
doc.select("table[cellpadding=6][cellspacing=0]:contains(Originally Posted by)").
```

Also `,` represents `OR` so it will try to find `somethingLikeThis` OR `somethingLikeThat` so it will generate additional results rather than narrowing them.